# Fetching data from json server in vue with axios

Tags: vue.js, axios, json-server

I would like to know is there is a way to do something like this without backend. I am calling all data from json server and displaying on home page:

```
    async created() {
        try{
            const products = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/products')

            this.products = products.data
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```

Now when i click any of these products i would like to redirect user to new page and would like to display data of that specific object from json server.
What i have built for now is when user click on any product he gets redirected to route /product, and everything is hardcoded there, no dynamic data.
I hope my question is clear, thank you everybody.

Comment: Can you please show what you tried so far ? Use vuex store to store the product data and then get it in the redirected route.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Vuex for this.

Move your method from `created()` to vuex's action and then call it in the hook.

The Vuex store's code is gonna be something like this:

```
state: {
  products: []
},
getters: {
  getProductById: (state) => (id) => state.products.find(product.id === id)
},
mutations: {
  SET_PRODUCTS(state, products) {
    state.products = products
  }
},
actions: {
  // this one is to call from the hook
  fetchProducts({ commit }) {
    return axios.get('http://localhost:3000/products').then(res => {
      commit('SET_PRODUCTS', res.data)
    })
  }
}
```

Then call something like this from the component you're redirecting from:

```
<router-link 
  :to="{
    name: 'Product', // im assuming this is the /product route's name
    params: {
      id: product.id // product.id is the id of your specific object your clicked on 
  }" 
>
  {{ product.productName }}
</router-link>
```

In your `<Product />` component, you get the specific object by id from your Vuex store by using the `getProductById()` getter.

In your template:

```
...
<!-- the id we've passed as a route params -->
<h1>{{ getProductById($route.params.id) }}</h1>
...
```

Comment: I moved products to vuex, and called fetchProducts form Home where i want all products to be shown and everything works but now when i click on the products i get error 'Product.vue?f2b7:7 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _ctx.getProductById is not a function'. I set getProductById to getters in vuex, and i set $router.push as you mentioned above. Btw what is .native supposed to do on Product component, I am getting error when i put it like that, it says 'native is deprecated'. Thank you.

Comment: go through the code i wrote again. i refactored it. should work now.
i changed the `getter` and the way you go to another route

Comment: <h1>{{ getProductById($route.params.id) }}</h1> this line is again throwing the same error. But when that line is deleted code works but same as before modification that you mentioned. Thanks for helping

Comment: i’m gonna need your code example